# Meta description showing other content other than specified in meta tag when inspected

Tags: seo, local-seo, meta-description

Please see the link as given.
https://bhetincha.com/gurkha-technologies

When searched for in google the meta description is different.
But when i view page source it the meta description is different.

Why is google not showing the coded meta description ?

Comment: Here is an article I wrote up giving some examples of why this happens in various circumstances. http://www.yangilbert.com/why-google-is-not-using-your-meta-description-tag  But in general Google will use your predefined description when it meets a certain expectation of length and readability. Otherwise it will pull some content from the page.

Comment: Please go the following link: [https://moz.com/blog/why-wont-google-use-my-meta-description](https://moz.com/blog/why-wont-google-use-my-meta-description)

Answer (score 2):

Note that Google may not show exact meta title and description you may have entered.

Google generally creates meta title and description based on search query and page content to serve best to the user.

In simple word, you can't control.

Having said that, if the page is optimised to rank for specific keywords and if you got rich content and meta details related to optimised keywords then you may see meta details based on the entry for related searches.

Answer (score 2):

I checked out your meta description and it doesn't really describe anything, it looks like keyword stuffing to me. And probably to Google as well, so they picked a few lines out of your page they think are relevant to the search query.